# Mysql trigger issue in multiple insert statements

Tags: mysql

I have this trigger:

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Insert1
AFTER INSERT ON sat_clientLocation
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO syncLoc VALUES (NEW.idOwnApp, NEW.idClient,NEW.idLocation,NEW.idMatca,NEW.numbers,NEW.idTypeLocation,NEW.txLocation,NEW.amLat,NEW.amLong,NEW.idUpdUser,NEW.tmUpdate,NEW.txLocationDtl, NEW.idUser ,NEW.idCustomer ,NEW.idCodeLocation , NEW.radius, NEW.zindex, NEW.amAuxLat, NEW.amAuxLong, NEW.isDelete,0,0);

END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

It works fine for one insert statement, but for import from a file no. I mention that the import file is insert the statements one by one, no from load data.

Thank a lot!

Comment: What does your import file look like and how are you importing.

Comment: MySQL triggers activate only for changes made to tables by SQL statements. This includes changes to base tables that underlie updatable views. Triggers do not activate for changes to tables made by APIs that do not transmit SQL statements to the MySQL Server. This means that triggers are not activated by updates made using the NDB API. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html

Comment: For example now i made an import of 18 statements, and my triggers works for last 12 statements, but not for first 6.

Comment: Are the 6 inserted to sat_clientLocation ? is there any chance they fail INSERT INTO syncLoc, I would add a debug_table to the trigger to capture every for each row to see if the trigger fires for each row.

Comment: All 18 are inserted in sat_clientLocation, but in syncLoc are only last 12 statements.

Comment: Then I suggest you add the debug_table and/or examine the data very carefully to see that it is compatible with syncLoc and that duplicate key errors are not firing,

Comment: Understand. I will try. Thanks!

Comment: No error, and my debug_table capture de statements who is inserted in syncLoc.

Comment: If all 18 records are captured in the debug_table and no errors are reported then the conclusion no matter how unlikely it iseems is  that the inserts to syncloc are happening but without the data and the table definitions I cannot do much more.

Comment: The problem is not the trigger don't see the data, i make  this:

Comment: The problem is not the trigger don't see the data, i make  this:   Trigger: Test_Insert
               Event: INSERT
               Table: sat_clientLocation
           Statement: BEGIN
INSERT INTO debug(proc_id, debug_output) VALUES ('DEBUG','triggerTest');
END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode:
             Definer: stdba@localhost
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
and the debug table is empty.